# How do you get the currently visible features in ol3 when the map was been rotated?

Tags: javascript, maps, gis, openlayers

To get the current features I use

```
var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
var features = layer.getSource().getFeaturesInExtent(extent);
```

However when a user spins the map around (e.g scrolling left 20 times.) this no longer works.

I can't figure out the function I need to use to map the current extent into the 'base' extent of the projection.